# Two minor typos in the "Register your Application" form

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the help text (on the right hand side) for the *Application Name* field on https://stackapps.com/apps/register:

1. I think this should be changed: " ... is built on the our platform ...". For example, removing "the".
2. "Feel free to include language on your site". Shouldn't it be "text" or "information" instead of "language"?

---

[alt text http://drmortensen.eu/1/until2038-01-19/StackApplications_RegisterApplication_Typo_2010-05-22_16c.png](http://drmortensen.eu/1/until2038-01-19/StackApplications_RegisterApplication_Typo_2010-05-22_16c.png)

Comment: Boy, people sure are are making a lot of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the the.

"Language" is perfectly cromulent in this context.